# How can I get the X data in a SELECT QUERY

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

For example: If I have a table where contains:

```
PRICES
1
5
3
8
2
8
```

If I'd like the the second element, how can I get it? Only that number.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @x int
set @x = 3

select top 1 
from (select top @x from table order by 1 desc) xx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$third_element = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT prices FROM the_table WHERE prices = '3'"), 0);
```

That selects the element, but I don't know why you would want to do it like that unless you had another row to select it from like, WHERE other_row = 'something', then you would arrive at 3.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible 
here is the solution for your answer try this.

```
create table prices
(
    price int 
)

insert into prices values (1)
insert into prices values (5)
insert into prices values (3)
insert into prices values (8)
insert into prices values (2)
insert into prices values (8)

select x.* from
(
    select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by price) as RowNumber,price 
    from prices
)x
where x.RowNumber=3
```